# How can I compute the integral $\int_{\psi(0,1)}\frac{z+z^*}{z-1/2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working out some exercises that came with some notes on complex analysis. Forgive me if the answer is obvious, it's just not my day today. The tools I can use are:

- Cauchy's Integral Theorem
- Cauchy's Integral Formula (also for derivatives)
- Deformation Theorem
- A bunch of other theorems but they all rely on the integrand being holomorphic inside and/or the region enclosed by the contours.
- **I can't use the Residue Theorem because it's not covered in the notes**

---

$$\int_{\psi(0,1)} \frac{Re(z)}{z-1/2}\text{ }dz$$

By $\psi_{(0,1)}$ we understand the set of points $\{z:|z| = 1\}$.

Here's what I've tried:

1. The first time I saw it, I tried to use Cauchy's Integral Formula. No good, because $Re(z)$ is not holomorphic anywhere.
2. I had the idea to rewrite $Re(z)$ as: $$\frac{z+z^*}{2}$$ and split the integral. This allows me to work out the first half using Cauchy's, but not the second half.
3. I tried rewriting the numerator as $z - i Im(z)$ but this looks about the same problem shifted on $Im(z)$ instead.
4. I tried rewriting the integral in its explicit parameterisation. It didn't end up simplifying much. I arrived at:$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i(\cos^2 (t) + \cos(t)\sin(t))}{e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}}dt$$
5. I am not very confident when it comes to variable substitution in complex analysis. I suspect this might make the integral much easier to work it. I understand from the notes that a reparameterisation must be a '**continuously differentiable bijective function**'.

The answer is listed as $\frac{i\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The first thing we need is the definition of $\psi(0,1)$.  If, for example, it is the circle $\{|z|=1\}$, then write $z^* = 1/z$ to get something analytic.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes! That is the definition. Precisely in the notes it's stated as 'The circular path parameterised as $a + be^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$. I took your hint and arrived at a partial fraction expansion. Since the complex logarithm is not a function, what is sensible from here? I can't just write down $log(z)$ as the integrand of $\frac{dz}{z}$, since $t$ varies across the *closed* interval, can I? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something..

Comment: How about using the "deformation theorem" to replace your contour by two small circles, one centered at each of the poles?

Comment: @GEdgar I ended up using Cauchy's on the partial fractions... not sure if we're saying the same thing but in essence, Cauchy's allows me to 'dodge' one pole. I ended up doing something like:
1. $\frac{dz}{z}$: Since $z \mapsto \{1\}$ is holomorphic, I can consider my $z_0 = 0$ and go from there to get $2i\pi$.
2. $-\frac{dz}{z-1/2}$. Same exact thing here, $z_0 = 1/2$ and hence I get $-2i\pi$.

Thank you for your help.. I guess this version is the same as the deformation one, but instead of splitting up the curve, I split up the integrand and kept the curve.

I got $\pi/2$ in total :)

Comment: $i\pi/2$ not $\pi/2$ - Just in case someone sees this and thinks the method gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\Re\pars{z} \over z - 1/2}\,\dd z & =
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{z + \overline{z}}/2 \over z - 1/2}\,\dd z =
{1 \over 2}\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{z + \pars{z\overline{z}}/z \over z - 1/2}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{z^{2}  + 1 \over z\pars{z - 1/2}}\,\dd z =
{1 \over 2}\, 2\pi\ic
\pars{{0^{2} + 1 \over 0 - 1/2} + {\pars{1/2}^{2} + 1 \over 1/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\ic\pars{-2 + {5 \over 2}} = \bbx{\large{\pi \over 2}\,\ic} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry if I'm misinterpreting your answer. Are you implicitly changing the curve before applying Cauchy's Integral Formula? *If not* then $f(z)$ needs to be holomorphic *on* and *inside* the contour. But $f(z)$ here has a denominator of $z-1/2$, and $1/2$ is inside the contour. Hence we get that $f(z)$ is not holomorphic inside the entire interior...

Comment: @Threnody $\displaystyle{\tt\color{red}{No}}$: I didn't change the curve. I took advantage of the fact $\displaystyle{\tt\color{red}{z\overline{z}} = 1}$. That renders the integrand as a holomorphic function on the integration path. Thanks.